# component unit testing services call resolved in the afterviewinit

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a component that implement afterviewinit and in the ngAfterViewInit I have some service calls and a call to check the actives tabs but I am struggling to setup my unit test:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
@ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

 ngOnInit(): void {}
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 const label = this.tabGroup._tabs.find((x: MatTab) => x.isActive).textLabel;
 
 //Service Call that use the label
 }
}
```

and in my test:

```
 describe('SomeComponent', () => {
        let component: SomeComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;
        
        
        beforeEach(waitForAsync(()=>{
        
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( declarations: [
                    SomeComponent,]
                    imports:[ MatTabsModule,]).compileComponents();
    });
                    
                                 
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(someComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    Object.defineProperty(component, 'tabs', { value: [], isActive: true});
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

        it('should be created', () => {
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });});
```

the test run ok but I am getting this error : `AfterAll TypeError: Cannot read property 'textLabel' of undefined`

I have tried using the:

```
afterEach(() => {
  fixture.destroy();
});
```

It seems to have resolved the first test but I am just wondering if there is a better way to do it.
PS: Basically my question is how should I mock objects that are set in the ngAfterViewInit, for instance the tabs are viewchild
Regards

Comment: Your code does not take into account that `Array.find()` can always return `undefined`, in case no match is found.

Comment: yeah that's what I am wondering how to set that up. What should I set up and where would I do it.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgGpwDYCuApjAIyYA0O+xMATJdYSQMyO7MwAs7NJArJgC6AWABQ40JFgBbOFGAALVPCQA6AGYBLMABMAFGAIzUAPhhGTKazCa0AbJgCUAbhgB6dzADe0BDoBzGAAfGAI9Im0wIl0AX3FJcAgQPCI1PBAA-TkFZQB+PNtnDy8ASQ0YHKUYLQgLEFhw3UidGJgQZCM8PAoYDKCqxTUYAHkoRSIEAHdakn6ioA)

Comment: There was a bit of code missing and I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MatTabGroup` is a dependency, I would suggest to mock it in the test.
In order to do so a testing library such as [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) can be used.

a sandbox with the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-chebyshev-wp7mr?file=/src/test.spec.ts

```js
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  // keep SomeComponent and mocks MatTabsModule
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(SomeComponent).mock(MatTabsModule));

  it('should be created', () => {
    // now we say that MatTabGroup._tabs should be a fake value
    MockInstance(MatTabGroup, '_tabs', new QueryList<MatTab>()).reset([
      // the value has 1 element
      // it is a fake MatTab with the desired value.
      MockService(MatTab, {
        isActive: true,
      }),
    ]);
    const component = MockRender(SomeComponent).point.componentInstance;

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```